How to enable logs from GCP instances to Google logs exporter?
Sometimes our GCP VM instances reboot without any apparent reason, and I want to view the logs of the VMs using the Google Logs Exporter service. In my GCP project, I have more than 200 instances, but I can see only 30–40 GKE nodes.
I saw logs from the hosts approximately a year ago, but now they have disappeared. No host settings have been changed.

I know it should work without installing any agents by default. If you install an agent, you will just see more information from the host, but it is not necessary.
How can I check if logs are enabled for the VM instances or the entire project?

I found the problem
The ServiceAccount used with VM does not have permissions to write logs.
These rights were missing:
resource "google_project_iam_member" "backend_machine_monitoring_metric_writer" {
  project = var.project
  role    = "roles/monitoring.metricWriter"
  member  = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.backend_machine.email}"
}

resource "google_project_iam_member" "backend_machine_logging_log_writer" {
  project = var.project
  role    = "roles/logging.logWriter"
  member  = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.backend_machine.email}"
}


To view the logs of the VMs using the Google Logs Exporter service or to check if logs are enabled for entire project:


In the Google Cloud console, go to the Logs Explorer page:

If you use the search bar to find this page, then select the result whose subheading is Logging.

Select a Google Cloud project, folder, or organization.

The log entries displayed by the Logs Explorer page depend on the following:
a) The resources searched for log entries.
b)The time-range setting.
c) Your Identity and Access Management (IAM) roles on the searched resources.
d) Your query filters the search results. For example, adding the query    severity>=ERROR results in the display listing only those log entries    with a severity level of at least ERROR.



To check if logs are enabled for the VM instances :

Go to the Logging > Logs Explorer page in the Google Cloud console.

In the Resource drop-down list, select VM Instance. A list of available VMs (instance_id) displays.

Click the VM that you want to view.


